# Are there any problems with setting up your own mail server?

Tags: email

I've been a web developer for many years but I never found the need to tinker with mail servers. I was always happy to just get a send mail error locally because I know when I up it on the production server, remotely hosted, everything will work.

But this time I really need my own mail server and I stumbled upon hMailServer w/c seems to be a pretty capable server.

What I'd like to know really is, is it logical to use your own mail server for production (not testing)? I have no problem with dedicating a cheap machine for it as mail server, and our office is always online anyway.

Will I have I have problems with international blacklists? Do mail servers have to REGISTER their IPs to whitelists and stuff?

I'm new to this running your own mail server stuff, but I do want the freedom to send as much group mail as I can to our organization. The web hoster's limitations has become a terrible inconvinience to our groups here. Although they offer bulk mail servers for a fee, I rather setup my own, so long as I know what problems I may encounter. Or is it really OK and my mail server can be as capable as any gmail/yahoo mail servers out there in terms of BASIC NEEDS and TRAFFIC, as well as reliability and not being blocked?

Comment: This question would probably have a better audience on ServerFault

Comment: Also (imo) it is better to write questions as readably as possible, so if you could capitalise 'I', avoid chat words such as 'coz' and not use unnecessary ellipsis (...) that would be great. Fixed a couple of questions for you just now.

Comment: ^ I fixed one or two questions for you just now, and forgotten I'd made the above request back in January. It's worth bearing in mind that questions will a little writing effort are less likely to attract downvotes, so it's worth doing!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main problem with setting up ones own mail server these days is not a technical issue, but a trust issue.

The problem of spam over the years has led to a variety of techniques being employed by ISPs to prevent it. A number of these involve avoiding forwarding on mail sent from untrusted sources. A privately operated mail server would definitely all into that category.

If you want your mail server to be trusted by the rest of the world, you need to implement a number of additional things, including [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) on your domain. If you're not prepared to do all that, and keep it maintained, then emails sent from your private mail server will end up in most people's spam folder.

So the answer really depends on whether you want to do it for private/internal use or as a public mailserver.

If you want a public mailserver that sends mail to the outside world, be prepared for a *lot* more work beyond simply setting up the server.

If you want it for personal use or use withing your organisation, then you don't need to worry about all that. But it would help to be aware of if all the same.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of info i was hoping for.. thank yo very much

Well this mail server will be our own (Company/Org) and to be honest I will be the only one who can send etc.. 

The main reason for this really is for our subscribers.. so i have no problems sending hundreds of mail / hour to all our members, teams and clients.. the server will send to any email address (gmail yahoo etc) but it wont be used by any other people but me.. it's really just for the php subscription application i developed.